# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined whaen import

Tags: jquery, import

there is bundle.js

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
import './app.js';
```

and there is app.js

```
$('#button').on('click', function(e) {
    ...
});
```

so I get this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

why imported script does not see jquery?

Answer (score 0):

you must load this script tag

< script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> < /script>

Comment: no, not must - I use webpack. If I move code from app.js into bundle.js - it's ok... what I forget to add in app.js?